# Windows 7 - Remote Desktop - Save Credentials ... It saves the incorrect username

Tags: windows-7

In windows 7, I'm selected the option to allow saving of login credentials.

However, when I login to these remote sites, it tries to put my computer name first followed by the login name.

So let's say my first successful login is:

user_name  password123

when I go back to remote in later, it will be saved as:

computer_name/user_name password123  and this will obviously fail.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the computer or domain name in when you type in the username.  If you don't specify one, the local computer name will be used.